# Widget not picking current URL when users navigate through History,pus/replace

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a widget. I want to grab current URL to do some specific tasks. I'm using window.location.href to grab the current location.

But when users come through history.push or history.replace to a page, window.location.href gives me only reference to page where last refresh happened and not the present location.

On extra refresh or if users land on a page through window.location, I get the present URL thereby do proper tasks.

I want do tasks on page regardless of how it was navigated to. I guess, I'm doing some mistake in my implementation.

I'm new to programming. I have already spend a week trying to fix this.

So really appreciate if someone can help me fix the problem.

```
  const [currentUrl, setCurrentURL] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
     
       let url = window.location.href;
       setCurrentURL(url)

 },[currentUrl]);


    const getPosts = () => {

         if (currentUrl === post.url)
          console.log("URL match") 

   };




return (

    <Popup posts={getPosts()}/>

)
```